# Why don't columns spread across page in Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny

I thought the full row was 12, so 4 3-wide columns should fill across the whole page, but this doesn't.
        library(shiny)

```
fluidPage(

    mainPanel(

      fluidRow(
        column(3,
               textInput("user_id", "User ID", width = NULL)
        ),

        column(3,
               textInput("name", "Organization name",value = "",width = NULL)
        ),
        column(3,

               textInput("address", "Address",value = "",width = NULL)
        ),
      column (3,
              textInput("zip", "Zip Code",value = "",width = NULL)
      )

      ) #row

    ) #panel

  ) #page
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to this community! Have you perhaps specified a side-bar or other menu somewhere? Also, perhaps check out https://rstudio.github.io/shinydashboard/get_started.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per default `mainPanel` has a `width` of 8. This can be seen when looking at the docs:

```
?shiny::mainPanel
```

> mainPanel(..., width = 8)

Therefore you have to explicitly state `width = 12` inside your `mainPanel` call.

---

```
fluidPage(

    mainPanel(

      fluidRow(
        column(3,
               textInput("user_id", "User ID", width = NULL)
        ),

        column(3,
               textInput("name", "Organization name",value = "",width = NULL)
        ),
        column(3,

               textInput("address", "Address",value = "",width = NULL)
        ),
      column (3,
              textInput("zip", "Zip Code",value = "",width = NULL)
      )

      ) #row

    , width = 12) #panel

  ) #page
```

..should do the trick.